# getting Error to to video from firebase to recycler view

Tags: java, android, firebase

when i run the app its load just title of video but not able to load video i dont know why?? i am tring to make an video streaming appliaction for my friends but the codes doesn't work. i have to load and play video from firebase where i have uploaded some videos
here is my code ⬇⬇

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.media3.common.MediaItem;
import androidx.media3.common.Player;
import androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;
    PlayerView playerView;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public void setExoplayer(Application application, String name, String videoUrl)
    {
        TextView textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
       playerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exoplayer_item);

       textView.setText(name);
       try{

           com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer = new com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(application).build();
           playerView.setPlayer((Player) simpleExoPlayer);
           MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoUrl);
           ((Player) simpleExoPlayer).setMediaItem(mediaItem);
           simpleExoPlayer.prepare();
           simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);


       }catch (Exception e)
       {

           Toast.makeText(application, "Failed to load try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }


    }
}
```

i am trying to load video from firebase to android studio app for streaming app, but its not working?

Comment: "the codes doesn't work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?